# How to scroll with ionic and have fixed content above

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following view:

```
 <ion-view ng-controller="recentDetailCtrl as vm">
   <ion-content  class="has-header">
      <div  style="padding:0px;">
        <my-video  video-url='vm.videoUrl'
           player-width="'100%'" player-height="'180px'"></my-video> 
    </div>
    <ion-scroll>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="comment in vm.comments">
                {{comment.text}}

        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-scroll>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

What I want is my list of comments to scroll but always have the video element fixed (so it stays scrolling below the video - similar to they way the mobile youtube app allows you scroll comments with the playing video fixed).

Currently when I scroll the video is moved up out of view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Move your video directive out of ion-content (all elements in ion-content will be scrolled).
2. Change the css of ion-content so that it does not occupy the upper half of the screen.
3. Add `position:fixed` and other css to your video directive, so that it takes up the upper half of your screen.

### HTML:

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Fixed Element at Top</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Fixed Element at Top</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <div class="fixed-header my-video">
       My fixed video content
    </div>
    <ion-content class="ion-content-below-my-video">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>1</ion-item>
        <ion-item>2</ion-item>
        <ion-item>3</ion-item>
        <ion-item>4</ion-item>
        <ion-item>5</ion-item>
        <ion-item>6</ion-item>
        <ion-item>7</ion-item>
        <ion-item>8</ion-item>
        <ion-item>9</ion-item>
        <ion-item>0</ion-item>
        <ion-item>1</ion-item>
        <ion-item>2</ion-item>
        <ion-item>3</ion-item>
        <ion-item>4</ion-item>
        <ion-item>5</ion-item>
        <ion-item>6</ion-item>
        <ion-item>7</ion-item>
        <ion-item>8</ion-item>
        <ion-item>9</ion-item>
        <ion-item>0</ion-item>
      </ion-list> 
    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

### CSS:

```
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

.fixed-header{
  margin-top:43px;
  /* 
   The ionic header bar is 43px in height,
   put your content below the header bar.
  */
}

.platform-webview.platform-ios.platform-cordova .fixed-header{
  margin-top:63px;
  /* On iOS, moving a div out of ion-content,
  I think you need to compensation for the 20px system status bar.
  so it's 43px+20px=63px. but I'm not so sure, it hasn't been tested.
  Test it yourself and make modifications if needed.
  */
}

.my-video
{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background:grey;
  color:red;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.ion-content-below-my-video{
  margin-top:200px!important;
}

.platform-webview.platform-ios.platform-cordova .ion-content-below-my-video{
  margin-top:220px;
  /*
  Same as .fixed-header
  */
}
```

Code pen here:

http://codepen.io/KevinWang15/pen/QNJEXX

Comment: Panic has set in..still not working. I should add my video element is a iframe (angular-youtube-video - not sure if that is causing the issue or my part time CSS skills are to blame). If you could provide a CodePen that would be amazing.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, it worked amazingly well. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: you can skip the 2. if you set z-index to the fixed element

Answer (score 18):

You can use `ion-fixed`: (Ionic 3.5.0)

```
<ion-content no-padding>
  <div ion-fixed class="map"></div>
  <div ion-fixed class="test_class">
    <h4>Bla Bla</h4>
  </div>
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
     <p>Test</p>
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Then on css:

```
.map {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 30%;
}

.test_class {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
top: 30%;
}
```

Ionic documentation has no reference on this one, yet.

Comment: This worked 100% for me thanks...not sure why I took me so long to find this! This should be marked as the approved answer!

Answer (score 2):

There is now in Ionic attribute `slot`. You can use it like that:

`<my-video slot="fixed"></my-video>`

It's shortly mentioned on Ionic documentation here: 

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#slots

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic4, you can use the `slot="fixed"` property for children of `<ion-content>` to achieve this.

Check the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#slots)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same use case. Moving the video content out of ion-content did the trick.

Comment: I am using Ionic5

Comment: Thanks! This simple trick actually works... just make sure you don't have `[fullscreen]="true"` set on the `<ion-content>` element as I did, because I copy/pasted an example ... doh! :-/