# How to make ion-header unmovable in ionic 2,3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want the ion-header with fixed position. When keyboard appears it also scroll up with the rest of the screen in iOS. How to make ion-header remain stick to the top while other part of a screen scroll up?

```
  <ion-header no-border>
      <button class="left-button" (click)="delete()" >
           Delete
      </button>
      <button class="right-button" (click)="save()" >
           Save
      </button>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content id="home" class="background-Image" no-bounce>
   <form [formGroup]="signup" novalidate>
    <!-- User email -->
    <div class="label">Wnat is your email?</div>
    <div class="row">
       <input class="input" autocorrect="off" type="email" placeholder=""  formControlName="email" (input)="onEmailChange()" (blur)="onEmailSubmitted()" (keyup.enter)="hideKeyboard()">
       <div class="validation-image">
           <img [src]=validationImageEmail [hidden]=!validationImageEmail />
       </div>  
    </div>
    <hr class="underline">    
  </form>  
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: Put `ion-header` outside of `ion-content` refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967780/how-to-scroll-with-ionic-and-have-fixed-content-above

Comment: It is already outside of ion-content

Comment: show us your code

Comment: @GabrielBarreto  i update my question

Comment: Is this your full page?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto i updated my code, for simplicity i here show only email input field, but real code have others input fields similar like email field

Answer (score 0):

I think that the case is that your header lacks of a navbar or toolbar. By my experience both have the sabe result, but as the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/) says:

> A Toolbar is a generic bar that is positioned above or below content. Unlike a Navbar, a toolbar can be used as a subheader. When toolbars are placed within an ion-header or ion-footer, the toolbars stay fixed in their respective location. When placed within ion-content, toolbars will scroll with the content.

So update your code like this:

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <button class="left-button" (click)="delete()" >
      Delete
    </button>
    <button class="right-button" (click)="save()" >
      Save
    </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Hope this helps.